# How to $compile a AngularJS directive for html that is in a Leaflet map control?

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I am trying to add a modal button to a leaflet map legend, with a AngularJS framework. Check out the map and modal buttons in this demo (modal buttons are the round info buttons): http://skyplan.ch/maps/dev/gwm6/

The modals are inserted using an Angular directive that looks like `<div infomodal="views/modals/popup.html">`.

I need to place such a button in the map legend. The problem is that since the legend is created dynamically, I need to $compile the modal directive. However, I only have access to the the content of the map control via the onAdd function of the control iControl.

I have tried calling $compile on the div that is generated in the onAdd function, but that hasn't worked. Has anybody tried to do something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using the following steps:

1. Got the scope of your main controller in a variable.

   ```
   var scope = angular.element('[ng-controller]:first').scope();
   ```
2. Created a custom button to test change of the language

   ```
   var $div = $('<div><button ng-click="lang=\'de\';changeLanguage();">Change Language to DE</button></div>');
   ```
3. Appended it to your leaf legend control

   ```
   $('.leaflet-bottom.leaflet-right:last .leaflet-control').append($div);
   ```
4. Force the angular to compile the appended the HTML control specifying the scope context of your main controller (1st step)

   ```
   angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(function($compile) {
       $compile($div)(scope);
   });
   ```
5. Click the button and the "magic" happens. :-)
6. You may need to append (**step 3**) and recompile (**step 4**) after each MapBox update.

Since I was outside your project, that was the steps necessary to achieve the solution, but once your have the directive logic (not ugglified) you have full access to the leafpanel thru the $element and the $compile using directive service injection.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It helped me realize that I was trying to $compile the div **before** it had been added to the map with map.addControl().